# Facing some issues when trying to create secrets in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-pod, configmap, kubernetes-secrets

I need to store some passwords and usernames in the secrets.YAML .but after the deployment getting this error .so unable to build the secret and access it in the pods.
Attaching the deployment.yaml and secretes .yaml below.

--Secrets.yaml

```sh
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      name: mysecret
    data:
       CassandraSettings__CassandraPassword: [[ .Environment ]]-abcd-cassandra-password
```

---Deployment.yaml

```sh
     env:
          - name: Password
            valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysecret
                  key: CassandraSettings__CassandraPassword
```

After deployment in TeamCity getting this error

> Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "STDIN": Secret in
>   version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: v1.Secret.ObjectMeta:
>   v1.ObjectMeta.TypeMeta: Kind: Data: decode base64: illegal base64 data
>   at input byte 3, error found in #10 byte of
>   ...|-password"},"kind":"|..., bigger context
>   ...|_CassandraPassword":"dev-bling-cassandra-password"},"kind":"Secret","metadata":{"annotations":{"kube|...
>   error parsing STDIN: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 33: did
>   not find expected '-' indicator

Comment: This -abcd-cassandra-password is the value base64 encoded?

Comment: Also, the space before ``` apiVersion: v1``` is not seems to be correct. It should be in the same level as kind. (I guess this is a copy-paste thing)

Comment: yeah , it was my mistake when copy-paste thing.both are in the same line.

Comment: How about the base64 encryption on values for ```name:``` and ```key:``` fields

Comment: Actually I will take the value of the passwords from the TeamCity variable seems, it is base64 encoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like type is missing, can you try as below,

---Secrets.yaml

```sh
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  CassandraSettings__CassandraPassword: [[ .Environment ]]-abcd-cassandra-password
```

---Deployment.yaml

```sh
    env:
      - name: Password
        valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
               name: mysecret
               key: CassandraSettings__CassandraPassword
```